# Github is acknowledging my commit but ignoring my push?

Tags: git, github

I made some changes and commited them. GitHub acknowledged accordingly, but `git push` returns `everything up-to-date.`. I have tried using the full repo path as well.

Comment: What does "acknowledged accordingly" mean?

Comment: Ok, well that's your local git repository then, not Github. What remote does `origin` point to? (`git remote show origin`) I've certainly made the mistake of pushing to a different repository than I thought I was pushing to.

Comment: It shows the repo I thought it would. I've solved the problem btw, by deleting the directory then cloning it again.

Comment: Could this be a branching issue? If you create a new branch locally it won't be pushed until you explicitly create a branch on the remote.

Comment: I think this is pretty difficult to answer right now. Crazyscot's guess is as good as any (for a newly created branch, you'll have to explicitly push it once: `git push origin foo-branch`). Was this a branch that was already on github as well, or not? (That is, Moshe, you probably do know.)

Comment: It was already on GitHub, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up forcing the push. It broke sone stuff but put my history where it should have been.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
git branch
#Shows your current branch, let's say $BRANCH
git push origin $BRANCH
```